# How can I tweak TUI emacs to pick the last visited frame instead of last created frame after delete-frame?

Tags: frames, terminal-emacs

When deleting current frame, Emacs always picks the last created frame to show.
How can I tweak it to pick the last visited frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out very easy.

```
(defun +amos/workspace-delete ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((frame (window-frame (get-mru-window t nil t))))
    (delete-frame)
    (select-frame frame)))
```

Here is a better solution which works when there are multiple windows in current frame.

```
(defun +amos/workspace-delete ()
  (interactive)
  (let (best-window best-time time)
    (dolist (window (window-list-1 nil 'nomini 'visible))
      (setq time (window-use-time window))
      (when (and (not (eq (window-frame window) (selected-frame)))
                 (or (not best-time) (> time best-time)))
        (setq best-time time)
        (setq best-window window)))
    (delete-frame)
    (select-frame (window-frame best-window))))
```

Comment: good answer with a built-in function

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
;;; ~/.emacs.d/init.el  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let (visited-frames)
  (advice-add 'select-frame :after
              (lambda (frame &rest _)
                (setq visited-frames (delq frame visited-frames))
                (push frame visited-frames)))
  (add-hook 'delete-frame-functions
            (lambda (frame)
              (setq visited-frames (delq frame visited-frames))))
  (add-hook 'after-delete-frame-functions
            (lambda (_)
              (when visited-frames
                (select-frame (car visited-frames))))))
```

I tested it by

1. <kbd>C-x 5 2</kbd>: `F1` -> `F2`
2. <kbd>C-x 5 2</kbd>: `F2` -> `F3`
3. <kbd>C-x 5 o</kbd>: `F3` -> `F2`
4. <kbd>C-x 5 o</kbd>: `F2` -> `F1`
5. <kbd>M-x delete-frame</kbd>: `F1` -> `F2`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't notice it until coming up with my own solution)